# How to get Azure Redis key hit count?

Tags: .net, azure, caching, redis, azure-redis-cache

Is there way to get all the keys stored in a azure redis cache with their hit counts?

I want to generate reports with the keys by their hit counts.

Comment: Redis doesn't provide a key-specific hit rate. (Only general hit rate) I don't know if Azure supports one.

Comment: Redis does not offer a hit rate metric directly. We can still calculate it like this:

`hit rate = keyspace_hits / (keyspace_hits + keyspace_misses)`

Comment: Please refer [View metrics with Azure Monitor metrics explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-how-to-monitor#view-metrics-with-azure-monitor-metrics-explorer)

Comment: Actually what exactly i am trying to achieve is, i need to just delete cache keys, which are not frequently used or used very less. is there a way to identify this?

Comment: Redis will automatically do that when it reaches the memory limit depending on your eviction policy configuration.